# How to parse list of objects with list of objects in it without external libraries

Tags: android, json, kotlin, parsing

I'm practicing parsing JSON string in Kotlin without using external libraries, and the problem starts when I have a list of objects with a list of objects in it.
This is my JSON

```
 {
   "id":"1",
   "title":"Schedule",
   "weekly_activity":[
      {
         "day":"Monday",
         "activity":[
            {
               "start":"07:30",
               "end":"",
               "activity_name":"Breakfast"
            },
            {
               "start":"07:30",
               "end":"09:30",
               "activity_name":"Escursion"
            },
            {
               "start":"09:30",
               "end":"11:00",
               "activity_name":"Talk"
            },
            {
               "start":"11:30",
               "end":"15:00",
               "activity_name":"Walk"
            },
            {
               "start":"15:00",
               "end":"16:30",
               "activity_name":"Lunch"
            },
            {
               "start":"Dalle",
               "end":"17:30",
               "activity_name":"Break"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "day":"Tuesday",
         "activity":[
            {
               "start":"07:31",
               "end":"",
               "activity_name":"Breakfast in the forest"
            },
            {
               "start":"07:31",
               "end":"09:31",
               "activity_name":"Walk"
            },
            {
               "start":"09:31",
               "end":"11:01",
               "activity_name":"Escursion"
            },
            {
               "start":"11:31",
               "end":"15:01",
               "activity_name":"Break"
            },
            {
               "start":"15:01",
               "end":"16:31",
               "activity_name":"Lunch"
            },
            {
               "start":"Dalle",
               "end":"17:31",
               "activity_name":"Free time"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

and this is my function to parse JSON:

```
 fun parseString (): Scheduler{

        val listOfActivity: ArrayList<Activity> = arrayListOf()
        val listOfWeeklyActivity: ArrayList<WeeklyActivity> = arrayListOf()
        val jsonStringScheduler = JSONObject(parseString)


        val id = jsonStringScheduler.getString("id")
        val title = jsonStringScheduler.getString("title")
        val weeklyActivityList =jsonStringScheduler.getJSONArray("weekly_activity")
        weeklyActivityList.let {
            (0 until it.length()).forEach{
                val weeklyActivity = weeklyActivityList.getJSONObject(it)
                val day = weeklyActivity.getString("day")
                val activityList = weeklyActivity.getJSONArray("activity")

                activityList.let {
                    (0 until it.length()).forEach{
                        val activity = activityList.getJSONObject(it)
                        val start = activity.getString("start")
                        val end = activity.getString("end")
                        val activityName = activity.getString("activity_name")

                        listOfActivity.add(Activity(start, end, activityName))
                    }
                }
                listOfWeeklyActivity.add(WeeklyActivity(day,listOfActivity))
            }
        }
        val scheduler = Scheduler(id, title, listOfWeeklyActivity)
        return  scheduler
    }
```

Every time I try to parse like this my "weekly activity" object has a list of both activities, but I need to have it like in JSON.

Comment: You should create new list for each activityList. When you try to parse the second 'weekly activity', the 'listOfActicity' already has activities of the previous one. In the other words, it's not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you only create `listOfActivity` once and you keep on modifying it in every iteration. Instead you have to create a new `listOfActivity` for every `weeklyActivity`. To solve this you need to move the declaration of `listOfActivity` inside the loop of `weeklyActivityList`, as following

```
fun parseString(): Scheduler {
    // remove this line ---> val listOfActivity: ArrayList<Activity> = arrayListOf()
    ...
    jsonStringScheduler.getJSONArray("weekly_activity")
    weeklyActivityList.let {
        (0 until it.length()).forEach {
            // Create new list of activity for every week here
            val listOfActivity: ArrayList<Activity> = arrayListOf()

            activityList.let {
                (0 until it.length()).forEach {
                    ...
                    listOfActivity.add(Activity(start, end, activityName))
                }
            }
            // listOfActivity for this week is complete, now add it to listOfWeeklyActivity
            // And for next WeeklyActivity create new listOfActivity 
            listOfWeeklyActivity.add(WeeklyActivity(day, listOfActivity))
        }
    }
    val scheduler = Scheduler(id, title, listOfWeeklyActivity)
    return scheduler
}
```